# How to scale the uploaded image in P5JS

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to write a stamp tool function that can upload an image as a stamp. Unfortunately, I am unable to scale the image as a stamp size. For example. the image remains the original size but the stamp size is 50x50. Therefore, the stamp can only show the top left corner of the image.

I tried to use the size or resize function in P5js but it doesn't work.

I initialise a global variable called "stamp" and the size.

```
    stamp = loadImage('./stamps/star.png');
    this.size = 50;
```

In the P5JS draw function

```
    image(stamp, mouseX, mouseY, this.size, this.size);
```

In my handleFile function

```
var handleFile = function (file) {
    print(file);
    if (file.type === 'image') {
        var targetStamp = createDiv();
        targetStamp.class('stamps');
        newStamp = createImg(file.data, '', () => { newStamp.size(100, AUTO) });
        targetStamp.child(newStamp);
        stampSelector = select(".stampSelector");
        stampSelector.child(targetStamp);

        targetStamp.mouseClicked(function () {
            var items = selectAll(".stamps");
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                items[i].style('border', '0')
            }
            targetStamp.style("border", "2px solid blue");
            stamp = newStamp;
        })
    } else {
        img = null;
    }
}
```

The size is succeeded to change by CSS, but cannot use as a stamp. Anyone can help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "cannot use as a stamp" it is not clear what the problem is. With a simplified version of your code it generally seems to work. However, it would appear that there is a bug with how the `image()` function handles source `<img>` elements that have been resized (it crops the source to the specified size, instead of using the original image dimensions, even when you explicitly specify source dimensions). There is a workaround though: using a CSS transform to control the size of the `<img>` element.

```js
let img;
let size = 50;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  let input = createFileInput(handleFile);
  input.position(10, 10);
  noLoop();
  background(0);
}

function draw() {}

function mouseClicked() {
  if (img) {
    image(img, mouseX, mouseY, size, size);
  }
}

function handleFile(file) {
  if (file.type === "image") {
    img = createImg(file.data, "uploaded image", "anonymous", () => {
      // This resizes the <img> tag, but will not effect the size of the image when drawn.
      // img.size(100, AUTO);
      img.style('transform', `scale(${100 / img.width})`);
      img.style('transform-origin', 'top left');
    });
  } else {
    img = null;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for debugging for me. And I found that I cannot pass the createImg to the global variable. I need to pass the file.data to create a new one.